# How to Check Current String Available in NsmutableArray..?

Tags: ios, iphone, nsmutablearray

I am Trying To Developed a Funcationality That Makes a Favourite 
Favourite is Working Perfect But When i Press Next or Previous Button its Crash...

i Dont know how to Check the Current Message is Exist in FavouriteArray..?
if is Exist Then FavouriteButton images Change to Favourite-ON.png otherwise its its image Favourite-OFF.png..

My Code is Below==================

```
    // Adding Current Message to Favourite Array

    - (IBAction)FavouritebtnClick:(id)sender  //Favourite Button Work Perfectly 
    {

        Make_Fav_Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array valueForKey:@"SMS"] objectAtIndex:row_no]];

        NSLog(@"Make Favourite TExt====%@",Make_Fav_Text);

        [DatabaseFiles InsertFav:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",Make_Fav_Text]];//insert to database

        [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    }
```

// Checking Current Message is Available in FavouriteArray

```
-(void)Check_Fav_Available
{
    for (NSString *Myfav in Check_Fav_Avail)
    {
        NSLog(@"MYFAV===%@",Myfav);
        if ([Myfav isEqual:sms.text])
        {
            [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"Found Favourite");

            //break;
        }
        else{
            NSLog(@"NOt Found");
            [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-copy-iphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }

}

//Next Button 

- (IBAction)Nextbtn:(id)sender
{


    row_no=row_no+1;
    lblno=row_no;
    lblno=lblno+1;

   [self Check_Fav_Available]; //Check Current Message in Favourite Array;

    if (row_no==[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array.count)
    {
        row_no=row_no-1;
//        lblno=lblno-1;
        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This is last SMS" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"this is last");
        NSLog(@"row no is %d",row_no);
    }
    else
    {
        if (row_no <=4)
        {
            sms.text=[[[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array objectAtIndex:row_no] objectForKey:@"SMS"];
            NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d",lblno,[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array.count];
            no_lbl.text=str;

            NSLog(@"row no is %d",row_no);
           [self Check_Fav_Available];


        }
        else
        {
            UIAlertView *Purchasealert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Purchase Category" message:@"Purchase to Enjoy More" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"Cancel" otherButtonTitles:@"Buy Message", nil];
            Purchasealert.tag=1710;
            [Purchasealert show];

            [self gostore];
            NSLog(@"this is last");
            NSLog(@"row no is %d",row_no);

        }
     }

}


//Previous Button

- (IBAction)Previousbtn:(id)sender
{

    //[FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-copy-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    row_no=row_no-1;
    lblno=lblno-1;

    if (row_no<0)
    {
        row_no=row_no+1;
        lblno=lblno+1;

        UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Alert" message:@"This is First SMS" delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
        [alert show];
        NSLog(@"this is last");
    } 
    else
    {
        [self Check_Fav_Available]; //Check Favourite available

        sms.text=[[[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array objectAtIndex:row_no] objectForKey:@"SMS"];

        NSString *str = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d - %d",lblno,[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array.count];
        no_lbl.text=str;
        [self Check_Fav_Available];

        NSLog(@"arr is %d",[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array.count);
        NSLog(@"row no is %d",row_no);
    }

}
```

Comment: What is the Crash Exception..?

Comment: use `isEqualToString` with caking String with in array or not instead of use isEqual

Comment: @kumarKI :*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa62e90'
*** First throw call stack:

Comment: @NitinGohel: Mr.Gohel the StringValue is Not Fixed its Change Everytime when i Presse Nextbutton Or PreviosButton...so its Working for Me..?

Comment: Put breakpoint , and check where exactly getting this exception..

Comment: @kumar:- i have Checked but when its come to [self Check_Fav_Available]Funcation in Nextbutton its Crash

Comment: what is the description of **Check_Fav_Avail**?

Comment: @Kumar :-(void)Check_Fav_Available
        {  for (NSString *Myfav in Check_Fav_Avail){
        NSRange favRange = [Myfav rangeOfString:sms.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];
        
        if (favRange.location != NSNotFound) {
            NSLog(@"Found");
            [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        } else {
            NSLog(@"Not found");
            [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-copy-iphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        }
    }
}

Comment: I'm asking what is the type of Check_Fav_Avail?? IS it NSarray Or etc...?

Comment: Yes..its Array...Below is the description..Check_Fav_Avail = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    Check_Fav_Avail = [[DatabaseFiles getData] valueForKey:@"Fav_Msg"];

Comment: PUt NSLog(@"%@",Check_Fav_Avail);

Comment: Used...but the Result remains the Same....it Crash

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this code.....

```
-(void)Check_Fav_Available
    {

            if (!([Check_Fav_Avail indexOfObject:sms.text]==NSNotFound))
            {
                [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
                NSLog(@"Found Favourite");

                //break;
            }
            else
              {
                NSLog(@"NOt Found");
                [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-copy-iphone"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            }


    }
```

Comment: :Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSConcreteMutableAttributedString countByEnumeratingWithState:objects:count:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xaa62e90'

Comment: :- Thank you So Much Mr.Raon....I have Used your Code as You Suggest...and its Works Completely...

Answer (score 0):

change your code to

```
for (NSString *Myfav in Check_Fav_Avail){
    NSRange favRange = [Myfav rangeOfString:sms.text options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch];

    if (favRange.location != NSNotFound) {
        NSLog(@"Found");
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Not found");
    }
}
```

Comment: @Touki: its Working but it Display only the Last Object and Remainig object Not Found..Pls Help

Answer (score 0):

Use this to compare...

```
if ([Myfav isEqualToString:sms.text])
        {
            [FavouriteBtnChange setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"FAv_On-iphone.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
            NSLog(@"Found Favourite");

            //break;
        }
```

This may be wrong..

```
Make_Fav_Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array valueForKey:@"SMS"] objectAtIndex:row_no]];
```

Instead, use this...

```
Make_Fav_Text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[[TabBarTutorialAppDelegate shareDelegate].level_array objectAtIndex:row_no] valueForKey:@"SMS"]];
```

Comment: :- No its Working Perfectly Load Currect Value Every time...but still i m goint to try as you suggest..Thanks

Comment: :- i have use the Code that you suggest..its Found the Favourite but when i press Nextbutton then its Crash..